# Is there a way, to send the value of a button to different pages in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am working on project and came across the problem: When i click a button on the e.g. //website/manageuser.php I want the value of the button in the //website/edituser.php

I tried using the `<value>` tag in a button but failed. I wasn't able to manage to transfer the value through the files.

My manageuser.php looks like this:
[image: Test]

After i press the e.g. "Delete" button, i get forwarded to the /deleteuser.php where I want to print the value behind the button. Unfortunatly, it isn't working with a StackOverflow Javascript script.

Image of my /deleteuser.php:

[image]

Code of the important part of manageuser.php:

```
<table>
    <tr>
            
<?php
$query = "select * from users";
$records = mysqli_query($con, $query); 
while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($records)) 
{   
?>
        <th>
            <p/>
<?php
    print($data["full_name"]);
?>                  
            <button type="button" value=" <?php print($data['full_name']) ?>" onclick="window.location.href='./edituser.php'">Edit</button>
            <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='./deleteuser.php'"> Delete </button> 
        </th>
<?php
}
?>  
    </tr>
</table>
```

Code of the important part of deleteuser.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      
      <script>
         var str1 = document.getElementById("btn").innerHTML;
         var str2 = document.getElementById("btn").value;
         document.write("Button text: "+str1);
         document.write("<br>Button value: "+str2);
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Stranded bit oj HTML `<p/>` ??

Comment: `document.getElementById("btn")` Do you have a HTML element with an `id="btn"`? I dont see one

Comment: Even if this was in a form, your button would not submit any value to begin with - `type="button"` makes it a "click button", it will not submit the form. And the URL you are going to with the click event handler, `./deleteuser.php`, does not contain any parameters either. You are not currently sending anything, that _could_ be received within that script.

Comment: The question seems very confused so I assume you also are confused.

Comment: no, I don't use any <from> tag, I just have these buttons, css and a bit more php in my manageuser.php

Comment: These should not be buttons to begin with. You do not actually want to trigger a delete or update action here _directly_ - you simply want to link to a different page, from where these actions will actually be triggered then. Linking to other pages is not a button's job - but that of a link, `<a href="...">`. You can pass your ID in the URL as a GET parameter, `<a href="./deleteuser.php?id=123">` If you want those links to _look like_ buttons, then format them accordingly via CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the value. Just append the value from `$data` as a query parameter to the URL.

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='./deleteuser.php?id=<?php echo $data['id'] ?>"> Delete </button>
```

Then in `deleteuser.php` you can use `$_GET['id']`.